Trouble exporting FBX files
I'm pretty new to Blender and have been working with a model (Rain) that I'm trying to export as an FBX with textures and animations. Blender freezes for 3-4 minutes while exporting the FBX, then the resulting FBX file throws a 'corrupted file' error when trying to load into a viewer. Any hints on what I may be doing wrong?
Thanks!

Hello, could you include your file/screenshots of the issue?

Could be something to do with this: .fbx export why there are no materials or textures plus the fact that the Rain model uses some pretty complicated animation code which the FBX format probably can't handle.

so what format should we export the file in ,if it complicated animations like rain? @john.

I've no idea to be honest. I doubt it was ever intended to be exported as it was originally created for one of Blender's own rendered videos.

Thanks for the responses/suggestions. After working on this a bit more, I found a few suggestions for FBX exporter settings: Armature > enable 'only deform bones', disable 'add leaf bones'. Bake Animation > enable 'NLA Strips' and 'All Actions'. This significantly reduced the export time, but the file still crashes in AutoDesk FBX Review. I decided to import it into the program that I actually need to use it in, touchDesigner and it imports with animation and some textures. Still trying to figure out why some textures are not importing...trying to figure out how to add screen shots here..
